# what is the difference between bounded and unbounded device?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I’m new to both iOS and BLE, so kindly bear with me if this question is very basic.

What is the distinction between bounded and unbounded devices?  I’m working with `CBCentralManager` for BLE in iOS, and I’m trying to figure out how to pair them through `CBCentralManager`.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to do anything different app, iOS will handle the binding if required.

Bounded connections are in a way "paired" to the iOS device. Once bounded they will not communicate to any other device. Bounding is controlled by the operating system (iOS). When a device that requires a bounded connection communicates with a iOS device, the iOS device will present a alert view asking if you wish to connect to the device.

Unbounded devices are continually broadcast their services and allows any iOS device to connect to it. The device will not bind to the specific iOS device and is free to connect to another iOS device at another time. This is the normal/recommended method for most BT4.0 sensors.

For both cases the application would normally store the UUID so it can establish the connection to the same device next time.

NOTE: Although unbounded devices are not "paired" with the iOS device, they will only communicate with a single iOS device at any one time.

Comment: I have one question to this. Do I need to know UUID before I connect to the device or I can get the UUID once I connected? Thanks

Comment: You need to know the UUID of the service that you're looking for.  You call the CBCentralManager's scanForPeripheralsWithServices:options: method, providing a list of service UUIDs.  If the device is advertising while you are scanning, your CBCentralManager's delegate's didDiscoverPeripheral: will be called.  There you will get the peripheral's UUID.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct terminology here is "bonded" not "bounded".

An non bonded peripheral will connect to any Central that attempts to discover it and establishes a connection.

A bonded peripheral has already paired previously and will automatically connect.

When a pairing persists between a peripheral and central it is bonded